# excludeRoute SDK API introduced in API 33. Is it supported for the Android VPN app on ChromeOS?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

I have an Android VPN app which uses [excludeRoute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder#excludeRoute(android.net.IpPrefix)) SDK API for Android OS version >= 13 while building the VPN interface for configuring the routes that should go outside of the tunnel.

**example:** sample-test.com resolves to 1.2.3.4 then I use excludeRoute(1.2.3.4)

My configuration works perfectly as expected with Android OS version >= 13, i.e, sample-test.com loads correctly as 1.2.3.4 goes outside of the tunnel.

However, the same app with the same VPN configuration does not work for ChromeOS having Android 13. Meaning, the routes excluded via [excludeRoute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder#excludeRoute(android.net.IpPrefix)) does not load the website (sample-test.com) ever (unless is disconnect the VPN)

My initial guess is as Google recently started the roll out for Android 13 on ChromeOS, do we know if [excludeRoute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder#excludeRoute(android.net.IpPrefix)) is supported for ChromeOS having Android version 13?

I had no luck in finding my assumption/theory in the below Google repositories:

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/117.0.5846.0:chrome/
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/

I just want to confirm if [excludeRoute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder#excludeRoute(android.net.IpPrefix)) is supported for the Android app on the ChromeOS having Android v13.